# Collapsible Menu Not Staying Open

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello ive  followed the instructions from this webspage [Add a Blogger-like collapsible archive block to your Drupal 7 site](http://planetbuhs.net/web-development/49-add-a-blogger-like-collapsible-archive-block-to-your-drupal-7-site) and suprised myself that everything seems to be 'sort of' working. As you can see from my 'collapsible block' on the right of [THIS PAGE](http://netmagpie.com/cosmic-nanny-place) that the block doesnt seem to want to stay open when viewing other months. I dont think this was the intended behaviour.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    // init: collapse all groups except for the first one
    $(".view-collapsible-archive ul").each(function(i) {
        if (i==0) {
            $(this).siblings("h3").children(".collapse-icon").text("▼");
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
 
    // click event: toggle visibility of group clicked (and update icon)
    $(".view-collapsible-archive h3").click(function() {
 
        var icon = $(this).children(".collapse-icon");
 
        $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle(function() {
            (icon.text()=="▼") ? icon.text("►") : icon.text("▼");
        });
    });
});
```

Could anyone suggest anything to me to make the menu block open on a month when clicked and to close the other 'months'?

thanks

Comment: This site is oriented toward questions about issues related to the programming profession (testing, software engineering, data structures, etc.), not questions about technical issues with a particular snippet of code.

Comment: Don't repost this question on Stack Overflow - if appropriate, it will be moved over.

Comment: thanks and im sorry. I wondered why i had never seen this place before.

Comment: You should change `children()` to `find()` because the icons are not direct children of the headers in your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code you have is already added inside the file `http://netmagpie.com/sites/all/themes/feverultra/js/feverultra.js` and by adding your file after that, you're binding twice to the event and the function toggles twice, so the elements open and close

If you want to only have one month open then you need to close any open months before opening the one that was clicked, something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    // init: collapse all groups except for the first one
    $(".view-collapsible-archive ul").each(function(i) {
        if (i==0) {
            $(this).siblings("h3").find(".collapse-icon").text("▼");
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    // click event: toggle visibility of group clicked (and update icon)
    $(".view-collapsible-archive h3").click(function() {

       $('.view-collapsible-archive ul:visible').not($(this).next('ul')).slideUp();

        var icon = $(this).find(".collapse-icon");
        $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle(function() {
            (icon.text()=="▼") ? icon.text("►") : icon.text("▼");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks chaps. I was hoping just to keep one menu list open (one month) at a time)I know this is outwith the discussion but all helpappreciated. thanks ah just seen your update koala. let me go try.....

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line:

```
$(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle
```

It says: "toggle the state of all the ul elements using a slide animation"

You will want to change this to slideDown when it's hidden in order to show it and slideUp when it's visible in order to hide it.

I would provide a code sample but I'm typing with one thumb on an iPhone at the moment.

Comment: ah brilliant koala dev your spot on. I did add it twice such was my haste to try and get it to work. Thanks very much.

Comment: ooops never meant to post. Its working fine now Andrew thanks but i would prefer the behaviour that you describe. I dont know who to give the thumbs up to now :( soz chaps errrrr

Comment: @RegGordon that is the default behavior for slideToggle, what behavior exactly would you like to change? also no offense but Andrew's answer was nowhere near the actual issue, your code was working fine

Comment: ah hah hah works brilliant koala much appreciated. Thanks very much for your time and efforts. thanks to all.